# assign CSS through jQ - syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to assign css properties through jQuery and use a var shortcut

```
var abc = 'visibility: \'hidden\', opacity: 0';
$('#ele').children().css({ abc });
```

but it's not taking the abc var name in the second line, I get Unexpected token in console.
how is my syntax incorrect?

Comment: Your CSS line in `abc` is not a valid format any known style setting context. Did you just make it up or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make your abc var look like the following:

```
var abc = {'visibility':'hidden','opacity':0};
```

and then pass it into the css function like this:

```
$("#ele").children().css(abc);
```

The first line is a "hash" or "dictionary", where you are assigning inner keys to values - by calling {abc} on the second line you would be calling {{....}}, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you do for some reason need to assign your initial var as a string - use JSON.parse to convert it into  object:

```
var abc = '{"visibility": "hidden", "opacity": 0}';

$('#ele').children().css(JSON.parse(abc));
```

Otherwise use @EmileVictor solution, by making it an object from the start.